# I need to get Lightning page name using lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, trailhead, lwc-oss

I need to get Lightning page name where I placed my lwc component, Suppose if place my lwc in record page and lightning page name is  "accountpage" the page name i have to get in lwc

Answer (score 3):

I use [CurrentPageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation):

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

...

    pageName;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    wiredCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
        this.pageName = currentPageReference?.attributes?.name;
    }

...
```